# Parsing S&P 500 Data from Wikipedia in GoLang

Tags: go, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I am trying to figure out how to parse the table of S&P 500 stock from this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies.

Python has nice libraries like lxml that help to take care of this but I'm trying to do the same thing in GoLang. I have already looked into making GET requests with "net/http" but am not sure how to perform the actual parsing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use this lib: https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery

It gives you easy to use jquery like selectors.

I made an example with your data:
http://play.golang.org/p/KdWUiiPxSU

Comment: Thank you. Just one more thing: Adding an error handler results in "Get https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies: stopped after 10 redirects" Any idea about how to mitigate this?